# Does the order of the equations in a coupled OIDENT solver matter?

Tags: python, system, differential-equations, odeint

My code runs, however, if i change the order of the equations defined in my formula my graphs changes as well. Can somebody tell me why this is? Now i do not know what the right graph is from this system.

```
def myFunction(r,t):
g = 9.81
L_L = 20 #draught
L_r = 20 #draught
L_d = 4 #ukc
u_s = 0.08
w_d = 60 #width vessel
rho = 1030
b_R = 1.0
b_L = 1.0
b_D = 1.0
A_s = 340*L_L
M_s = 40000*10^3 

w_L = r[0]
w_r = r[1]
u_1 = r[2]
u_2 = r[3]
u_3 = r[4]
u_4 = r[5]
u_d = r[6]
p_1 = r[7]
p_2 = r[8]
p_3 = r[9]
p_4 = r[10]
deltap_L = r[11]
deltap_R = r[12]

u_1 = (L_L*u_s + w_L*u_2)/w_L
u_2 = (w_d*u_d)/w_L
u_d = (w_r*u_3)/w_d
u_3 = (w_L*u_2)/w_r
u_4 = (L_r*u_s + w_r*u_3)/w_r
dwLdt = u_s
dwrdt = - u_s  
du1dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L + deltap_L/L_L) - b_L*u_1 
du2dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L - deltap_L/L_L) - b_L*u_2
du3dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r + deltap_R/L_r) - b_R*u_3
du4dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r - deltap_R/L_r) - b_R*u_4
duddt =  - g*((p_3-p_2)/L_d) - b_D *u_d
dp1dt = - u_1
dp2dt = - u_1
dp3dt = + u_4
dp4dt = + u_4
ddeltap_Ldt = -u_1
ddeltap_Rdt = u_4 
#M_s = (g*rho*A_s*((p_1+p_2)/2 + deltap_L/6 - (p_3+p_4)/2 - deltap_R/6))/u_s


return (dwLdt, dwrdt, du1dt, du2dt, du3dt, du4dt, duddt, dp1dt, dp2dt, dp3dt, dp4dt, ddeltap_Ldt, ddeltap_Rdt)
r0 = [10,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
t = np.linspace(0,20,10000)
r = odeint(myFunction, r0, t)

w_L = r[:,0]
w_r = r[:,1]
u1 = r[:,2]
u2 = r[:,3]
u3 = r[:,4]
u4 = r[:,5]
ud = r[:,6]
p_1 = r[:,7]
p_2 = r[:,8]
p_3 = r[:,9]
p_4 = r[:,10]
deltap_L = r[:,11]
deltap_R = r[:,12]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, u1)
plt.plot(t, u2)
plt.plot(t, u3)
plt.plot(t, u4)
plt.plot(t, ud)
plt.legend(('$u_1$', '$u_2$', '$u_3$', '$u_4$', '$u_d$'))
plt.xlabel('Time ($s$)')
plt.ylabel('Fluid velocity ($m/s$)')
```

[graph first code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtC5e.png)

if the equations in the code are in this order:

```
    dwLdt = u_s
    dwrdt = - u_s  
    du1dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L + deltap_L/L_L) - b_L*u_1 
    du2dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L - deltap_L/L_L) - b_L*u_2
    du3dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r + deltap_R/L_r) - b_R*u_3
    du4dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r - deltap_R/L_r) - b_R*u_4
    duddt =  - g*((p_3-p_2)/L_d) - b_D *u_d
    u_1 = (L_L*u_s + w_L*u_2)/w_L
    u_2 = (w_d*u_d)/w_L
    u_d = (w_r*u_3)/w_d
    u_3 = (w_L*u_2)/w_r
    u_4 = (L_r*u_s + w_r*u_3)/w_r
    dp1dt = - u_1
    dp2dt = - u_1
    dp3dt = + u_4
    dp4dt = + u_4
    ddeltap_Ldt = -u_1
    ddeltap_Rdt = u_4 
    #M_s = (g*rho*A_s*((p_1+p_2)/2 + deltap_L/6 - (p_3+p_4)/2 - deltap_R/6))/u_s
```

the graph is like this:

[graph second mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4eAI.png)

Why is this the case?

The code is now:

```
  def myFunction(r,t):
     g = 9.81
     L_L = 20 #draught
     L_r = 20 #draught
     L_d = 4 #ukc
     u_s = 0.08
     w_d = 60 #width vessel
     rho = 1025
     b_R = 1.0
     b_L = 1.0
     b_D = 1.0
     A_s = 340*L_L
     M_s = 40000*10^6

     w_L = r[0]
     w_r = r[1]
     u_1 = r[2]
     u_2 = r[3]
     u_3 = r[4]
     u_4 = r[5]
     u_d = r[6]
     p_1 = r[7]
     p_2 = r[8]
     p_3 = r[9]
     p_4 = r[10]
     deltap_L = r[11]
     deltap_R = r[12]


     u_1 = (L_L*u_s + w_L*u_2)/w_L
     u_2 = (w_d*u_d)/w_L
     u_3 = (w_L*u_2)/w_r
     u_4 = (L_r*u_s + w_r*u_3)/w_r
     u_d = (w_r*u_3)/w_d

     du1dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L + deltap_L/L_L) - b_L*u_1 
     du2dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L - deltap_L/L_L) - b_L*u_2
     du3dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r - deltap_R/L_r) - b_R*u_3
     du4dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r + deltap_R/L_r) - b_R*u_4
     duddt =  - g*((p_3-p_2)/L_d) - b_D *u_d




     dp1dt =  - u_1
     dp2dt =  - u_1
     dp3dt = + u_4
     dp4dt = + u_4
     ddeltap_Ldt =  - u_1
     ddeltap_Rdt =  u_4 

     dwLdt = u_s
     dwrdt = - u_s 

     deltap_R = 6*(((p_1+p_2)/2) + (deltap_L/6) - ((p_3+p_4)/2)) 

     return (dwLdt, dwrdt, du1dt, du2dt, du3dt, du4dt, duddt, dp1dt,     dp2dt, dp3dt, dp4dt, ddeltap_Ldt, ddeltap_Rdt)

r0 = [10,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
t = np.linspace(0,125,100000)
r = odeint(myFunction, r0, t)

wL = r[:,0]
wr = r[:,1]
u1 = r[:,2]
u2 = r[:,3]
u3 = r[:,4]
u4 = r[:,5]
ud = r[:,6]
p1 = r[:,7]
p2 = r[:,8]
p3 = r[:,9]
p4 = r[:,10]
deltapL = r[:,11]
deltapR = r[:,12]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second code snippet you are referring to e.g. `u_1` before you assign it. The same goes for u_2 ... u_4.  So whatever the values of those are before the assignments get used in the calculations for du1dt...duddt

Comment: They don't have a value before the assignment, so how can it work then?

Comment: There must be some value or you'd get an error like `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'u_1' is not defined`

Comment: Initially `u_1,...,u_4` are input components `2,..,5`, it is bad style to use the same variable names for different content in the same function.

Comment: I changed the variable names, still I have the problem that the order of the equations influences my outcome.

Comment: Would you please post your (whole) modified function that shows the bad behavior?

Comment: I put the entire code at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the code block

```py
     u_1 = (L_L*u_s + w_L*u_2)/w_L
     u_2 = (w_d*u_d)/w_L
     u_3 = (w_L*u_2)/w_r
     u_4 = (L_r*u_s + w_r*u_3)/w_r
     u_d = (w_r*u_3)/w_d
```

you change all the `u` values. Of course it makes a difference in the function if you compute further values with the modified or unmodified `u` values.

The easiest thing to do is not to re-use these variable names. Change `u` to `v` on the left side and then check whether in uses further down you really wanted to use the modified `v` value or the `u` value.  Your original code with that change would be

```py
     v_1 = (L_L*u_s + w_L*u_2)/w_L
     v_2 = (w_d*u_d)/w_L
     v_3 = (w_L*v_2)/w_r
     v_4 = (L_r*u_s + w_r*v_3)/w_r
     v_d = (w_r*v_3)/w_d

     du1dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L + deltap_L/L_L) - b_L*v_1 
     du2dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L - deltap_L/L_L) - b_L*v_2
     du3dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r - deltap_R/L_r) - b_R*v_3
     du4dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r + deltap_R/L_r) - b_R*v_4
     duddt =  - g*((p_3-p_2)/L_d) - b_D *v_d




     dp1dt =  - v_1
     dp2dt =  - v_1
     dp3dt = + v_4
     dp4dt = + v_4
     ddeltap_Ldt =  - v_1
     ddeltap_Rdt =  v_4
```

Now any re-arrangement of the indicated type will cause an error that some variable used on some right side was not previously defined.

Comment: However, the values that need to be obtained are the u1, u2, u3 etcetera. Technically, v1 and u1 are not the same variable anymore right? Whilst physically they are.

Comment: Then I have to suspect that you do not understand the task sufficiently well if you can not clearly say what the input and output variables are. As per your code, u1, u2, etc are components of the input vector r. That middle block where I compute the v components from the inputs may be wrong, but that depends on what the underlying problem is. There may be a reason you do what you originally did, but you would need to explain why, and why it is a good reason. Then the output does not only depend from the position of that block in the code, but also from the order of its lines.